# does size of int matter? sudoku optimization

Tags: java, arrays, optimization, binary, int

I am trying to optimize an algorithm (Sudoku) in Java for a class and I'd like to know the following:

*1. Does the size of an int significantly affect the speed at which basic operations are performed?
I.e dividing an int 8 digits long vs 2 digits long

*2. Is there any way to use binary? Or bitfields (I'm not sure how bitfields work exactly)

For example I need to store the allowed values of each square so instead of making an NxNxN array is there any way to have just an NxN array for each row/column storing something like 011010001 which would mean 2,3,4,9 can be placed in that position? I could do boolean I guess but I was also planning to convert every multidimensional array into a single dimension (since I have heard Java treats 2D arrays as arrays of arrays unlike c++) then mod out each value (which would work with integers).

*3. If the above is possible would it be more efficient to have a multidimensional array storing booleans or more efficient to have a single array length N^2 or N^3 with integers.
If it makes a difference N will be between 9 and 25. I am not so much worried about the 9 but I feel 25^3 can set me back quite a bit.

I don't know if I should expect a definitive answer but any insight or estimation would be great.

Comment: ["Premature optimization is the root of all evil"](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization).

Answer (score 0):

Every `int` is 32 bits wide. It doesn't matter how many of these bits are set.

Of course you can access the individual bits in an `int`, that's what [bitwise and bit shift  operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html) are for.

And yes, replacing a `boolean[]` by an `int` will speed up operations, particularly if the same logical operation needs to be applied to all bits in the `int`. For instance, if we have bitmasks for the available numbers in a row, column and box we can find the bitmask for the numbers available in a cell by

```
int availableInCell = availableInRow & availableInColumn & availableInBox;
```

Comment: If I am understanding this correctly availableInRow etc would be a 0 or a 1? Is there any special format to it? I have see 0b, 0x and others is that something different?

Comment: No, each int contains 32 bits, 9 of which are used to represent, for each of the 9 numbers, whether the number is still available. For instance, 0b111111111 would mean all 9 numbers are still available. To access an individual bit in a number, use the shifting operators.

Answer (score 0):

Integer division should always take the same amount of time regardless of the values. If you use "long" instead of "int" it might take longer (at least on a 32 bit machine).

You can use bit shifting operators ( >> , >>>, or << ) to store multiple boolean flags in an int. You can also use bitwise-and ('&' not '&&' ) or bitwise-or ( '|' not '||' ) to parse or store boolean flags in an int.  See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html . As far as efficiency I am not sure, that might depend on other aspects of your algorithm.

By the way 25^3 = 15625 which is not very big. Even at 4 bytes per int 25^3*4=62500 which is 64k, still not very big. I'd worry more about the CPU efficiency of your algorithm

Comment: Yes but I am afraid if I have several even primitive operations inside that loop and if the loop is nested within another loop it will significantly slow it down no?

Answer (score 0):

It absolutly makes sense to represent the grid in a one-dimensional array of an element that has at least as many bits as you need. For example, for a normal sudoku, a short[81] would be sufficient.

Comment: The code has to be flexible for larger sudoku grids. Would using a short limit me in any methods or operations that would otherwise work for ints?

Comment: If you need more than 16bits, yes. It is also no great deal to use int[] or long[].